# Gmail marking self-signed certs as unencrypted

Tags: tls, encryption, gmail

Just a quick question/answer pair to share what I've learned this morning.

Gmail marks self-signed certs for TLS as unencrypted in their interface now. This is obviously wrong. How has anyone else got around this?

Comment: It's not obviously wrong. Without pinning, self-signed certs might as well be unencrypted because they're not providing any protection from active MITM attacks.

Comment: Are you sure this changed? It still shows self signed as encrypted for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a quick fix if you run your own mail server, and possibly web server alongside - use your letsencrypt certs. In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
```

Not sure of the difference between enabling it for smtpd only (does that cover send/receive? A topic for another question...) but both are there to be sure, anyway.

I also updated the LE script to reload postfix when certs were renewed:

```
web_service2='postfix'
/usr/sbin/service $web_service2 reload
```

Added those lines to `/usr/local/sbin/le-renew-webroot-SITE` which runs on a cron job.

Comment: PS - you can add them to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` as well, but you don't need to to get rid of the red padlock in Gmail.

Comment: PPS - finally I also added the mail subdomain to the domains list in the config at `/usr/local/etc/le-renew-webroot-SITE.ini`, so that the hostname matches. Then renewed the cert. Again, not essential, but good for completeness. Tested with [SSL Tools](https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers).